# JavaScript extract continues failing intermittently

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008, arguments, logic, scheduled-tasks

I've taken on a new role in the tech support team and tasked to resolve an on going and intermittent issue with one of our nightly data extracts failing.

The extract process sends a data file every night containing a record of transactions completed that day. A scheduled task runs each night, with a second run if the first failed, then sends an email notification based on the status.

The scheduled task opens a CMD file which then runs a JS script command to execute a custom stored procedure on the SQL database. 
Each night the file is replaced with a new file and this logic writes the status to file.

The below is the output log information which indicates an invalid call error:

---

Custom_Extract_Second_Run.js started at Tuesday, 19 January 2016 8:15:00 PM
C:\DataExtract\Custom_Extract_Second_Run.js(341, 4) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument

---

Custom_Extract.js started at Wednesday, 20 January 2016 8:03:00 PM
Script causes an exception.
Exception number: 0x5007
Description:'objRs.EOF' is null or not an object
Task ended at Wednesday, 20 January 2016 8:08:13 PM. Total Messages Sent: 0

---

Custom_Extract_Second_Run.js started at Wednesday, 20 January 2016 8:15:00 PM
Task ended at Wednesday, 20 January 2016 8:20:00 PM. Total Messages Sent: 1

---

Custom_Extract.js started at Thursday, 21 January 2016 8:03:01 PM
Script causes an exception.
Exception number: 0x5007
Description:'objRs.EOF' is null or not an object
Task ended at Thursday, 21 January 2016 8:07:56 PM. Total Messages Sent: 0

---

Custom_Extract_Second_Run.js started at Thursday, 21 January 2016 8:15:00 PM
Script causes an exception.
Exception number: 0x3704
Description:Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
Task ended at Thursday, 21 January 2016 8:19:49 PM. Total Messages Sent: 0

---

Custom_Extract.js started at Friday, 22 January 2016 8:03:00 PM
C:\DataExtract\Custom_Extract.js(318, 4) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument

---

Custom_Extract_Second_Run.js started at Friday, 22 January 2016 8:15:00 PM
C:\DataExtract\Custom_Extract_Second_Run.js(341, 4) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument

---

We had to reverse-engineer the scripts used to work out how it actually behaves, however not at a confident level to make changes. The extract logic was developed a long time ago (10 to 12 years ago), therefore likely very old and outdated logic.

Below is the javascript logic used in the extract.

```js
var QUERY_NAME_1 = "Custom_Extract";
var QUERY_NAME_2 = "Custom_Extract_UpdateDate";
var LOG_FILE_NAME = "DataExtract_error.log";
var EXTRACT_FILE_NAME = "Extract";

var DB_SERVER_NAME = "sql6";
var DB_DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
var DB_DATABASE_USER_NAME = "username";
var DB_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "password";

var DateTimeNow = new Date();
var DATE_VALUE = DateTimeNow.getDate() + "/" + (DateTimeNow.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + DateTimeNow.getFullYear();
var EMAIL_SUBJECT_HEADER = "Email Extract Header - Extract Date - " + DATE_VALUE;
var EMAIL_SUBJECT = EMAIL_SUBJECT_HEADER + " Successful";
var EMAIL_SUBJECT_ERROR = "Unsuccessful - " + EMAIL_SUBJECT_HEADER;

var EmailCount = 0;
var DELIMITER = "|";
var STRING_SQL_FAILED = "SQL Failed";
var strScript = "";
var strMsg = "";

var ARG_REPORT_PATH = "";
var ARG_MAIL_SERVER = "";
var ARG_KEEP_BACKUP_COPIES = 0;
var ARG_EMAIL_FROM = "";
var ARG_EMAIL_TO = "";

function ParseCommandLineParams() {
  var cmdArgs = WScript.Arguments;
  for (i = 0; i < cmdArgs.length; i++) {
    // Get next argument
    arg = cmdArgs(i);

    // Each argument is in the form a=b. Split the two components
    j = arg.search(/=/);
    if (j == -1) {
      WScript.Echo("Invalid arguments arg = " + arg);
      return false;
    }

    argName = arg.substring(0, j);
    argValue = arg.substring(j + 1, arg.length);
    switch (argName) {
      case "/reportPath":
        ARG_REPORT_PATH = argValue;
        break;
      case "/mailServer":
        ARG_MAIL_SERVER = argValue;
        break;
      case "/keepBackupCopies":
        ARG_KEEP_BACKUP_COPIES = parseInt(argValue);
        break;
      case "/from":
        ARG_EMAIL_FROM = argValue;
        break;
      case "/to":
        ARG_EMAIL_TO = argValue;
        break;
      default:
        WScript.Echo("Invalid arguments. Name = '" + argName + "' Value = '" + argValue + "'");
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}


function DisplayUsage() {
  WScript.Echo("Usage: cscript DataExtract.js");
  WScript.Echo("      [/m=<Report path directory where it creates file>]");
  WScript.Echo("      [/from=<from-line in email>] [/to=<to-line in email>]");
  WScript.Echo("      [/machinename=<Email Server name>] [/databaseConfig=<Database Config Setting file>]");
  WScript.Echo(" ");
  WScript.Echo("   /m              - unc path to mail directory      (default: ..\\reports\\)");
  WScript.Echo("   /from           - from-line in email              (default: Tejas Magia <>");
  WScript.Echo("   /to             - to-line in email                (default: Tejas Magia <>");
  WScript.Echo("   /machinename    - email server name               (default: EXCHANGE2 ");
  WScript.Echo("   /databaseConfig - DataBase Setup Config           (default: ..\\..\\..\\..\\config\\config.txt ");

  return;
}

function DisplayParameters() {
  WScript.Echo("Parameters:");
  WScript.Echo("      ARG_REPORT_PATH=[" + ARG_REPORT_PATH + "]");
  WScript.Echo("      ARG_EMAIL_FROM=[" + ARG_EMAIL_FROM + "]");
  WScript.Echo("      ARG_EMAIL_TO=[" + ARG_EMAIL_TO + "]");
  WScript.Echo("      ARG_MAIL_SERVER=[" + ARG_MAIL_SERVER + "]");
  WScript.Echo("      DB_SERVER_NAME=[" + DB_SERVER_NAME + "]");
  WScript.Echo("      DB_DATABASE_NAME=[" + DB_DATABASE_NAME + "]");

  return;
}

function GetConfigCDO() {
  var objConf = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration");
  objFields = objConf.Fields;
  objFields.Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2;
  objFields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = ARG_MAIL_SERVER;
  objFields.Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25;
  objFields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30;
  objFields.Update();

  return objConf;
}

function GetDatabaseConnection() {
  // SQLOLEDB is very sensitive to noise between client & server, and always mistaken certain
  // noise as returned result set; ODBC is better way to go for now
  var objCon = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
  objCon.Open(
    "Driver={Sql Server};APP=" + strScript +
    ";Server=" + DB_SERVER_NAME +
    ";Database=" + DB_DATABASE_NAME +
    ";user id=" + DB_DATABASE_USER_NAME +
    ";password=" + DB_DATABASE_PASSWORD +
    ";OLE DB Services=0"
  );

  return objCon;
}



//
// BEGIN MAIN PROGRAM
//

strMsg = "**************************************************";
WScript.Echo(strMsg);
WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(strMsg);

strScript = String(WScript.ScriptName);
DateTimeNow = new Date();
strMsg = strScript + " started at " + DateTimeNow.toLocaleString();
WScript.Echo(strMsg);
WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(strMsg);

if (!ParseCommandLineParams()) {
  DisplayUsage();
  WScript.Quit(0);
}

DisplayParameters();

try {
  var objCon = GetDatabaseConnection();
  var objCmd = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
  objCmd.ActiveConnection = objCon;
  objCmd.CommandText = QUERY_NAME_1;
  objCmd.CommandType = 4; // adCmdStoredProc
  objCmd.CommandTimeout = 1800;
  var objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("Return", 3, 4); // adInteger, adParamReturnValue
  objCmd.Parameters.Append(objParam);

  WScript.Echo("Before execution");
  if (ARG_KEEP_BACKUP_COPIES == 1) {
    var objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    if (objFSO.FileExists(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "3.txt")) {
      var File3 = objFSO.GetFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "3.txt");
      File3.Delete();
    }
    if (objFSO.FileExists(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "2.txt")) {
      var File2 = objFSO.GetFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "2.txt");
      File2.Move(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "3.txt");
    }
    if (objFSO.FileExists(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "1.txt")) {
      var File1 = objFSO.GetFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "1.txt");
      File1.Move(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "2.txt");
    }
    if (objFSO.FileExists(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + ".txt")) {
      var File0 = objFSO.GetFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + ".txt");
      File0.Move(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "1.txt");
    }
  }

  var objRs = null;
  try {
    objRs = objCmd.Execute();
  } catch (er) {
    try {
      objRs = objCmd.Execute();
    } catch (er2) {
      try {
        objRs.Close();
      } catch (er3) {
        WScript.Echo("Error found even after 2nd run attempt!");
      }

      var strError = "First run failed";

      // Send error email     
      var objConf = GetConfigCDO();
      var objMsg = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Message");
      objMsg.Configuration = objConf;
      // objMsg.To = ARG_EMAIL_TO;
      objMsg.To = "support@sumtotal.com.au";
      objMsg.From = ARG_EMAIL_FROM;
      objMsg.Subject = EMAIL_SUBJECT_ERROR;
      objMsg.TextBody = strError;
      objMsg.send();

      // Log error in output file
      var objTStreamLE = objFSO.CreateTextFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + ".txt", true);
      objTStreamLE.WriteLine(strError);
      objTStreamLE.Close();
    }
  }

  if (objRs.EOF) {
    objRs.Close();

    // check return code after closing the record set
    var rc = objCmd(0);
    if (rc == 100010) {
      WScript.Echo("Another instance is running. Bail out");
    } else if (rc == 0) {
      WScript.Echo("Found no records for users");
    } else {
      var objError = new Error(rc, STRING_SQL_FAILED);
      throw objError;
    }
  } else {
    // Update Last Update Date
    objCmd.ActiveConnection = objCon;
    objCmd.CommandText = QUERY_NAME_2;
    objCmd.CommandType = 4; // adCmdStoredProc
    objCmd.CommandTimeout = 1800;
    objCmd.Execute();

    var objTStreamLE = objFSO.CreateTextFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + ".txt", true);
    while (true) {
      if (objRs.EOF) {
        // we have to send the last mail
        strContentType = "";
      } else {
        var strApplicantID = new String(objRs("EmpID"));
        var strCourse_Code = new String(objRs("Event_Code"));
        var strCourse_Name = new String(objRs("Course_Name"));
        var strCompletion_Date = new String(objRs("Completion_Date"));
        var strGrade_Name = new String(objRs("Grade_Name"));

        var strBodyInfo = strApplicantID + DELIMITER +
          strCourse_Code + DELIMITER +
          strCourse_Name + DELIMITER +
          strCompletion_Date + DELIMITER +
          strGrade_Name;

        WScript.Echo(strBodyInfo);
        objTStreamLE.WriteLine(strBodyInfo);
      }

      if (objRs.EOF) {
        break;
      }

      objRs.MoveNext;
    }
    objTStreamLE.Close();
    objRs.Close();
  }

  var objConf = GetConfigCDO();
  var objMsg = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Message");
  objMsg.Configuration = objConf;
  objMsg.To = ARG_EMAIL_TO;
  objMsg.From = ARG_EMAIL_FROM;
  objMsg.Subject = EMAIL_SUBJECT;
  objMsg.TextBody = EMAIL_SUBJECT;
  objMsg.send();

  EmailCount++; // How many email sent. it will be always one email in this case.

  objCon.Close();
} catch (e) {
  var objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var objTStreamErrorLog = objFSO.CreateTextFile(errorFile, true);
  objTStreamErrorLog.WriteLine(strMsg);


  if (e.description == STRING_SQL_FAILED) {
    strMsg = "Failed to execute " + QUERY_NAME_1 + ".\nReturn code:" + String(e.number);
  } else {
    strMsg = "Script causes an exception.\nException number: 0x" + String(e.number & 0xFFFF) + "\nDescription:" + e.description;
  }

  objTStreamErrorLog.WriteLine(strMsg);
  objTStreamErrorLog.close();

  var errorFile = ARG_REPORT_PATH + LOG_FILE_NAME;
  var theFile_1_Abs = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(errorFile);
  var objConf = GetConfigCDO();
  var objMsg = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Message");
  objMsg.Configuration = objConf;
  objMsg.To = ARG_EMAIL_TO + ";" + ARG_EMAIL_FROM;
  objMsg.From = ARG_EMAIL_FROM;
  objMsg.Subject = EMAIL_SUBJECT_ERROR;
  objMsg.TextBody = "The attached file contains a error log file of any issues that arose during the DataExtract process";
  objMsg.AddAttachment(theFile_1_Abs);
  objMsg.send();

  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(strMsg);
  WScript.Echo(strMsg);

  objFSO.DeleteFile(errorFile); // delete log file generated.

  var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
  if (!objShell.LogEvent(1, "iX Learning Server Task(" + strScript + "): " + strMsg)) {
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("Failed to log an event");
  }
}

DateTimeNow = new Date();
strMsg = "Task ended at " + DateTimeNow.toLocaleString() + ". Total Messages Sent: " + EmailCount.toString();
WScript.Echo(strMsg);
WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(strMsg);

//
// END MAIN PROGRAM
//
```

**2nd run**

```js
var QUERY_NAME_1 = "Custom_Extract_Second_Run";
var QUERY_NAME_2 = "Custom_Extract_UpdateDate";
var QUERY_NAME_3 = "Custom_Extract_GetRunStatus";
var LOG_FILE_NAME = "DataExtract_error.log";
var EXTRACT_FILE_NAME = "Extract";

var DB_SERVER_NAME = "sql6";
var DB_DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
var DB_DATABASE_USER_NAME = "username";
var DB_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "password";

var DateTimeNow = new Date();
var DATE_VALUE = DateTimeNow.getDate() + "/" + (DateTimeNow.getMonth()+1) + "/" + DateTimeNow.getFullYear();
var EMAIL_SUBJECT_HEADER = "Email Extract Header - Extract Date - " + DATE_VALUE;
var EMAIL_SUBJECT = EMAIL_SUBJECT_HEADER + " Successful";
var EMAIL_SUBJECT_ERROR = "Unsuccessful - " + EMAIL_SUBJECT_HEADER;

var EmailCount = 0;
var DELIMITER = "|";
var STRING_SQL_FAILED = "SQL Failed";
var strScript = "";
var strMsg = "";

var ARG_REPORT_PATH = "";
var ARG_MAIL_SERVER = "";
var ARG_KEEP_BACKUP_COPIES = 0;
var ARG_EMAIL_FROM = "";
var ARG_EMAIL_TO = "";

function ParseCommandLineParams()
{
   var cmdArgs = WScript.Arguments;
   for(i = 0; i < cmdArgs.length; i++)
   {
      // Get next argument
      arg = cmdArgs(i);
        
      // Each argument is in the form a=b. Split the two components
      j = arg.search(/=/);
      if(j == -1)
      {
         WScript.Echo("Invalid arguments arg = " + arg);
         return false;
      }
                                                 
      argName  = arg.substring(0, j);
      argValue = arg.substring(j+1, arg.length);
      switch(argName)
      {
         case "/reportPath":
            ARG_REPORT_PATH = argValue;
            break;
         case "/mailServer":
            ARG_MAIL_SERVER = argValue;
            break;
         case "/keepBackupCopies":
            ARG_KEEP_BACKUP_COPIES = parseInt(argValue);
            break;
         case "/from":
            ARG_EMAIL_FROM = argValue;
            break;       
         case "/to":
            ARG_EMAIL_TO = argValue;
            break;
         default:
            WScript.Echo("Invalid arguments. Name = '" + argName + "' Value = '" + argValue + "'");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


function DisplayUsage()
{
   WScript.Echo("Usage: cscript DataExtract.js");
   WScript.Echo("      [/m=<Report path directory where it creates file>]");
   WScript.Echo("      [/from=<from-line in email>] [/to=<to-line in email>]");
   WScript.Echo("      [/machinename=<Email Server name>] [/databaseConfig=<Database Config Setting file>]");
   WScript.Echo(" ");
   WScript.Echo("   /m              - unc path to mail directory      (default: ..\\reports\\)");
   WScript.Echo("   /from           - from-line in email              (default: Tejas Magia <>");
   WScript.Echo("   /to             - to-line in email                (default: Tejas Magia <>");
   WScript.Echo("   /machinename    - email server name               (default: EXCHANGE2 ");
   WScript.Echo("   /databaseConfig - DataBase Setup Config           (default: ..\\..\\..\\..\\config\\config.txt "); 

   return;
}

function DisplayParameters()
{
   WScript.Echo("Parameters:");
   WScript.Echo("      ARG_REPORT_PATH=[" + ARG_REPORT_PATH + "]");
   WScript.Echo("      ARG_EMAIL_FROM=[" + ARG_EMAIL_FROM + "]");
   WScript.Echo("      ARG_EMAIL_TO=[" + ARG_EMAIL_TO +"]");
   WScript.Echo("      ARG_MAIL_SERVER=["+ ARG_MAIL_SERVER +"]");
   WScript.Echo("      DB_SERVER_NAME=[" + DB_SERVER_NAME + "]");
   WScript.Echo("      DB_DATABASE_NAME=[" + DB_DATABASE_NAME+ "]");

   return;
}

function GetConfigCDO()
{
   var objConf = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration"); 
   objFields = objConf.Fields;       
   objFields.Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2;
   objFields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = ARG_MAIL_SERVER;
   objFields.Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25;
   objFields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30;
   objFields.Update();

   return objConf;
}

function GetDatabaseConnection()
{
   // SQLOLEDB is very sensitive to noise between client & server, and always mistaken certain
   // noise as returned result set; ODBC is better way to go for now
   var objCon = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
   objCon.Open(
                "Driver={Sql Server};APP=" + strScript + 
                ";Server=" + DB_SERVER_NAME +
                ";Database=" + DB_DATABASE_NAME +
                ";user id=" + DB_DATABASE_USER_NAME + 
                ";password=" + DB_DATABASE_PASSWORD +
                ";OLE DB Services=0"
                ); 

   return objCon;
}



//
// BEGIN MAIN PROGRAM
//

strMsg = "**************************************************";
WScript.Echo(strMsg);
WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(strMsg);

strScript = String(WScript.ScriptName);
DateTimeNow = new Date();
strMsg = strScript + " started at " + DateTimeNow.toLocaleString();
WScript.Echo(strMsg);
WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(strMsg);

if (!ParseCommandLineParams()) 
{
   DisplayUsage();
   WScript.Quit(0);
}

DisplayParameters();

try
{
   var objCon = GetDatabaseConnection();
   var objCmd = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
   var objRs = null;

   var runStatus = 0;
   try
   {  
      // Get Run Status
      objCmd.ActiveConnection = objCon;
      objCmd.CommandText = QUERY_NAME_3;
      objCmd.CommandType = 4; // adCmdStoredProc
      objCmd.CommandTimeout = 1800;
      objRs = objCmd.Execute();

      runStatus = objRs("Status");
   }
   catch (er5)
   {
   }

   if (runStatus < 1)
   {
      objCmd.ActiveConnection = objCon;
      objCmd.CommandText = QUERY_NAME_1;
      objCmd.CommandType = 4; // adCmdStoredProc
      objCmd.CommandTimeout = 1800;
      var objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("Return", 3, 4); // adInteger, adParamReturnValue
      objCmd.Parameters.Append(objParam);

      WScript.Echo("Before execution");
      if (ARG_KEEP_BACKUP_COPIES == 1) 
      {
         var objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
         if (objFSO.FileExists(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "3.txt")) 
         {
            var File3 = objFSO.GetFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "3.txt");
            File3.Delete();
         }
         if (objFSO.FileExists(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "2.txt")) 
         {
            var File2 = objFSO.GetFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "2.txt");
            File2.Move(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "3.txt");
         }
         if (objFSO.FileExists(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "1.txt")) 
         {
            var File1 = objFSO.GetFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "1.txt");
            File1.Move(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "2.txt");
         }
         if (objFSO.FileExists(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + ".txt")) 
         {
            var File0 = objFSO.GetFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + ".txt");
            File0.Move(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + "1.txt");
         }
      }

      try
      {  
         objRs = objCmd.Execute();
      }
      catch (er)
      {
         try
         {
            objRs = objCmd.Execute();
         } 
         catch (er2) 
         {
            try
            {               
               objRs.Close();
            }
            catch (er3)
            { 
               WScript.Echo("Error found even after 2nd run attempt!");
            }

            var strError = "An unexpected error has occured during the run of this routine. " +
                           "and send through a manual extract. If you do not hear back from us by 1pm, please do not hesitate to call " +
                           ".";

            // Send error email     
            var objConf = GetConfigCDO();      
            var objMsg = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Message");
            objMsg.Configuration = objConf;
            objMsg.To = ARG_EMAIL_TO + ";email@email.com.au";
//            objMsg.To = ARG_EMAIL_TO;
            objMsg.From = ARG_EMAIL_FROM;
            objMsg.Subject = EMAIL_SUBJECT_ERROR;
            objMsg.TextBody = strError;
            objMsg.send();

            // Log error in output file
            var objTStreamLE = objFSO.CreateTextFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + ".txt", true);
            objTStreamLE.WriteLine(strError);
            objTStreamLE.Close();
         }
      }

      if (objRs.EOF) 
      {
         objRs.Close();

         // check return code after closing the record set
         var rc = objCmd(0);
         if (rc == 100010) 
         {
            WScript.Echo("Another instance is running. Bail out");
         }
         else if (rc == 0) 
         {
            WScript.Echo("Found no records for users");
         }
         else
         {
            var objError = new Error(rc, STRING_SQL_FAILED); 
            throw objError;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         // Update Last Update Date
         objCmd.ActiveConnection = objCon;
         objCmd.CommandText = QUERY_NAME_2;
         objCmd.CommandType = 4; // adCmdStoredProc
         objCmd.CommandTimeout = 1800;
         objCmd.Execute();

         var objTStreamLE = objFSO.CreateTextFile(ARG_REPORT_PATH + EXTRACT_FILE_NAME + ".txt", true);
         while (true)
         {
            if (objRs.EOF) 
            {
               // we have to send the last mail
               strContentType = "";
            }
            else
            {
               var strApplicantID = new String(objRs("EmpID"));
               var strCourse_Code = new String(objRs("Event_Code"));
               var strCourse_Name = new String(objRs("Course_Name"));
               var strCompletion_Date = new String(objRs("Completion_Date"));
               var strGrade_Name = new String(objRs("Grade_Name"));

               var strBodyInfo = strApplicantID + DELIMITER + 
                                 strCourse_Code + DELIMITER + 
                                 strCourse_Name + DELIMITER + 
                                 strCompletion_Date + DELIMITER + 
                                 strGrade_Name;
   
               WScript.Echo(strBodyInfo);
               objTStreamLE.WriteLine(strBodyInfo);
            }

            if (objRs.EOF) 
            {
               break;
            }

            objRs.MoveNext;
         }
         objTStreamLE.Close();
         objRs.Close();
      }
     
      var objConf = GetConfigCDO();      
      var objMsg = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Message");
      objMsg.Configuration = objConf;
      objMsg.To = ARG_EMAIL_TO;
      objMsg.From = ARG_EMAIL_FROM;
      objMsg.Subject = EMAIL_SUBJECT;
      objMsg.TextBody = EMAIL_SUBJECT;
      objMsg.send();

      EmailCount++; // How many email sent. it will be always one email in this case.

   }
   objCon.Close();
}
catch (e)
```

Following a great deal of testing and analysis, we're unable to pinpoint the root cause as both jobs seem to fail intermittently, some nights the extract produces data and other nights no data at all. 
Below are our test results based on manual run via cmd and via the task both producing intermittent failed and success results, with no particular pattern.

**Test results:**

Execute 1st run via command prompt
1st run - Fail
2nd run - Fail
3rd run - Successful
4th run - Successful
5th run - Successful

Execute Scheduled task - 'First run'

1st run - Successful
2nd run - Successful
3rd run - Successful
4th run - Fail - Scheduler failed
5th run - Fail - Scheduler failed

Execute Scheduled task - Sequential First followed by Second run

1st run - First run successful, second run successful but no file generated
2nd run - First run unsuccessful, ran second job - successful
3rd run - First run successful, second run successful but no file generated
4th run - First run unsuccessful, ran second job - successful

A possible cause may be due to timeout; however, each run takes the same time to complete (approx. 3 minutes) whether failed or successful.

We recently upgraded the environment from Windows Server 2005 to Windows Server 2008 and noticed the issue starting occurring after implementation. No change was made to the logic or SQL procedures. 
Would Server 2008 handle the logic in such a way to break the routine?

Comment: Line 258 looks suspicious

Comment: Is the code you posted `Custom_Extract.js`, `Custom_Extract_Second_Run.js` or something else entirely?

Comment: Those numbers in the error messages are line number and column of the file.   Why don't you look at that code or post it in your question.

Comment: the error `'objRs.EOF' is null or not an object` will occur if the second `objRs = objCmd.Execute();` fails, because the code blindly continues despite it failing ... `Custom_Extract.js(318, 4)` perhaps `objTStreamErrorLog = objFSO.CreateTextFile(errorFile,true);` is failing, and no error checking is done ... that's just two of the errors, others are just as easy to locate, but the debugging would be up to you

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX,

I have attached the second run code to the post.
The second run is slightly different to handle first failed attempt.

Just some background on the SQL query extract. The procedure extracts data from the last 24 hours and then stamps an update date at the time of extract. On the next extract, the procedure looks at the last update stamp on the database and uses this to extract the next 24 hours worth of data and so forth.

The query on the SQL side takes approximately 3 minutes.

Comment: `I have attached the second run code to the post` - wonderful news. not going to do your work for you, Jimmy ... and you haven't posted the whole code, you've posted 337 lines, and there's an error on line 341

Comment: @JaromandaX

We moved line 335 where the variable is defined to line 318 so next the next time it ran it would execute correctly. However, following this change we continued to receive failures therefore reverted the changes back to original.

Thank you for your advice. We will continue to investigate.

Comment: perhaps post how these scripts are executed ... lots of command line arguments, no idea if you're using them right

Comment: `We moved line 335 where the variable is defined to line 318` - the script is now 321 lines long ... so, not sure what the heck you're doing to the posted script, how the hell can anyone match up line numbers **for you** if you keep changing what you've posted

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX,

Apologies am new to Stackoverflow and etiquette on what to post. 
I definitely dont want anyone to recode this for me as it is our mess. Just wanting to get some advice as we are at a whim at the moment.
I'll do some more analysis and post the results on here.
Thank you for your time and advice so far. It definitely helps.
Cheers

Comment: I apologise if I appear negative in any way